# How to externalize Spring Boot application.properties to tomcat/lib folder

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, maven-3

I need a configuration free, deployable war, myapp1.war that can retrieve the configuration files from the tomcat/lib folder.
As I have other web applications coexisting on the same Tomcat: myapp2.war, myapp3.war, I need this layout:

```
tomcat/lib/myapp1/application.properties
tomcat/lib/myapp2/application.properties
tomcat/lib/myapp3/application.properties
```

This way I can build the war files without any properties files inside the war and deploy on any server.

I have read the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) but it explains how to set the location when running as a jar:

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

I cannot figure out how to do this for the case of multiple coexisting war files.

I would like to know if this is possible or should I give up on Spring Boot and go back to the traditional Spring MVC applications.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you set the `spring.config.location` property. Can be system or environment variable. Could even be JNDI or the servlet context. So it doesn't have to be a argument to your jar. However instead of using `application.properties` you might want to give the file another name instead of each app its own directory. You can then simply load it from a default, globally set location.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A solution could be to load application-{profile}.properties as @PropertySource annotations as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691812/can-propertysources-be-chosen-by-spring-profile) suggests, but then the logging system wont work, as you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html).

> The logging system is initialized early in the application lifecycle
>   and as such logging properties will not be found in property files
>   loaded via @PropertySource annotations.

This means that your logging properties in application-{profiles}.properties like:

```
logging.config=classpath:myapp1/logback.xml
logging.path = /path/to/logs
logging.file = myapp1.log
```

will be ignored and the logging system wont work.

To solve this I have used the SpringApplicationBuilder.properties() method to load properties at the beginning, when the application is configured. There I set the 'spring.config.location' used by Spring Boot to load all the application-{profiles}.properties:

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder) {
        return springApplicationBuilder
                .sources(Application.class)
                .properties(getProperties());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .sources(Application.class)
                .properties(getProperties())
                .run(args);
    }

   static Properties getProperties() {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("spring.config.location", "classpath:myapp1/");
      return props;
   }
}
```

Then I have moved the properties files from src/main/resources to src/main/resources/myapp1

```
.
├src
| └main
|   └resources
|     └myapp1
|       └application.properties
|       └application-development.properties
|       └logback.xml
└─pom.xml
```

In the pom.xml I have to set the scope of embedded tomcat libraries as "provided".
Also, to exclude all properties files in src/main/resources/myapp1 from the final war and generate a configuration free, deployable war:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <packagingExcludes>
              **/myapp1/
            </packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Then in Tomcat I have

```
├apache-tomcat-7.0.59
 └lib
   ├─myapp1
   |  └application.properties        
   |  └logback.xml
   └─myapp2
     └application.properties
     └logback.xml
```

Now I can generate the configuration free war and drop it into the apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps folder. Properties files will be resolved using the classpath, independently for each webapp:

```
   apache-tomcat-7.0.59/lib/myapp1
   apache-tomcat-7.0.59/lib/myapp2
   apache-tomcat-7.0.59/lib/myapp3
```

Comment: Very helpful answer. However, whatever I do I cant seem to get Spring to see the logback.xml in the myapp1 folder, even if I set logging.config=classpath:myapp1/logback.xml, it just ignores it. Have you found any way around this?

Comment: @ChrisGeo What do you have inside apache-tomcat-7.x.xx/lib/myapp1 ? Have you checked that no application.properties files are inside the generated war?

Comment: @DanielMora i tried with the same code what you have given here. But it is not working, don't know what i have missed in config. As a jar it is working well, but failed when deployed as war. I'm getting this exception >>>>> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist >>>>> don't know how to fix this, cloud you please help me..

Comment: Thanks! Solved my initial problem and helped me understand the difference between Spring-Boot-Apps-as-WARs and standalone Jars with the embedded Tomcat.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that "_The default search path classpath:,classpath:/config,file:,file:config/ is always used, irrespective of the value of `spring.config.location`_" from [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

Comment: Interesting solution. How can you manage the initialization (i.e., SpringApplicationBuilder.properties() ) in tests? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

With Spring 4.2 and @Annotation config and tomcat on linux serveur

In your Application class set the @PropertySource like that :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application-yourapp.properties"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.yourapp")
public class YourAppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ...
}
```

Now you just need to include the property file in your classpath

**In production**

Deploy your .war files ( or anything ) on tomcat, and put your application-yourapp.properties anyway on your production machine. ( for exemple in /opt/applyconfigfolder/application-yourapp.properties" )

Then in your tomcat ( here tomcat 7 ) open `bin\catalina.sh`

You have this line

```
# Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup,
# but allow them to be specified in setenv.sh, in rare case when it is needed.
CLASSPATH=
```

Just add the path of the folder which contains application.properties

```
CLASSPATH=:/opt/applyconfigfolder
```

If you have already some classpath define you can add it

```
CLASSPATH=:/opt/applyconfigfolder:/yourpath1:/yourpath2:
```

I haven't try with windows but I think there is no problem

**In Dev ( with eclipse )**

```
├src
| └main
|   └ ....
└config
| └application-yourapp.properties
```

instead of `src/main/resources/application-yourapp.properties`

Now in eclipse add your config folder to classpath, go to "Run Configurations" of your tomcat server ( or equivalent ) and add the folder Config to User Entries

[image]

Ok that's it, your application.properties is out of the application and your project run perfectly in dev environment.

Comment: Instead of mutating `bin/catalina.sh`: prefer to append to the file `bin\catalina.sh` (creating if it does not yet exist). `echo 'CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/applyconfigfolder' >> "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"`

Comment: correction: I mean to say "prefer to append to the file _`$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"`_.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Mora gave a good solution but instead of using spring.config.location you can use spring.config.name (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files), so you can have different properties file for different web apps in the same tomcat/lib directory:

```
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder) {
        return springApplicationBuilder
                .sources(Application.class)
                .properties(getProperties());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .sources(Application.class)
                .properties(getProperties())
                .run(args);
    }

   static Properties getProperties() {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("spring.config.name", "myapp1");
      return props;
   }
}
```

I think that the lib directory is for third party libraries not for storing configuration properties for your web apps.
So I think that a better solution is to add an external folder as additional classpath folder using shared.loader property in conf/catalina.properties:

shared.loader=${catalina.base}/shared/configurations

You can put your application properties   app1.properties, app2.properties, ecc.. in apache-tomcat-7.0.59/shared/configurations.

Before finding Daniel Mora solution of overridding configure method of SpringBootServletInitializer my solution was to add a context.xml in src/main/webapp/META-INF with this content:

```
<Context>
    <Environment name="spring.config.name" value="myapp1" type="java.lang.String" override="false" description="define the property file for srping boot application"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: One potential downside to using `spring.config.name` is that bundled properties get precedence over say external property files, and so it's not possible to override built-in properties from outside. Using `spring.config.location` or better still, `spring.config.alternate-location` allows property overriding because the provided locations take precedence.

Comment: Why you say that bundled properties get precedence over external property files? Can you make an example? Thank you