# When deployed Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FacesContext must not be null

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm running this project on intellij with tomcat 9

This is a mixed flavor of Springboot and JSF

I bearly have any issue in dev mode but as soon as I take the war file and import it to tomcat server (deployment) I  begin to experience issue

1. Running the project from the springboot startup doesnt work, I get the FaceContext must not be Null issue.
2. Using an external tomcat (see image) the projects runs just fine though moving the war to a staging  tomcat environment the project then fails.

```html
   [enter image description here][1]
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2020-06-28 22:46:42.621  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.primefaces.california.Application    : Starting Application v2.0.0 on cf79a22333e6 with PID 1 (/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/nicole_nms_war/WEB-INF/classes started by root in /usr/local/tomcat)
2020-06-28 22:46:42.627  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.primefaces.california.Application    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-28 22:46:43.819  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-28 22:46:43.988  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 158ms. Found 10 repository interfaces.
2020-06-28 22:46:44.583  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8dff9f8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-06-28 22:46:44.644  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1969 ms
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2020-06-28 22:46:45.208  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-06-28 22:46:45.215  WARN 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2020-06-28 22:46:46.191  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-06-28 22:46:46.280  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2020-06-28 22:46:46.433  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2020-06-28 22:46:46.434  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-06-28 22:46:46.683  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2020-06-28 22:46:46.933  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2020-06-28 22:46:50.392  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-28 22:46:51.840  WARN 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FacesContext must not be null
2020-06-28 22:46:51.844  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-28 22:46:51.846  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-06-28 22:46:51.866  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-06-28 22:46:51.883  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-28 22:46:51.891 ERROR 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FacesContext must not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) [catalina.jar:8.5.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754) [catalina.jar:8.5.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730) [catalina.jar:8.5.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1140) [catalina.jar:8.5.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875) [catalina.jar:8.5.35]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514) [na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FacesContext must not be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContextUtils.java:52) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(FacesContextUtils.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.primefaces.california.backend.controller.ApplicationController.init(ApplicationController.java:57) ~[classes/:2.0.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Pom file

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>california</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>california</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.683</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Controller Class

```html
package org.primefaces.california.backend.controller;

import *imports*; 
 

@Data
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@Component
public class ApplicationController extends AbstractController {

    private static final String INSTITUTION_KEY = "institution_key";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationService applicationService;
   

    public void initParentEnrolmentProcess() {
       //logic
    } 
 
}
```

Failing point in abstract class

```html
package org.primefaces.california.backend.controller;

import other.imports
import org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils;
 

@Slf4j
public class AbstractController {

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        FacesContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())
                .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
                .autowireBean(this);
    }
 
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/401.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
<!--    <context-param>-->
<!--        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>-->
<!--        <param-value>Development</param-value>-->
<!--    </context-param>-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>california-#{guestPreferences.theme}</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/primefaces-california.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.california.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

Faces-config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

    <name>primefaces_california</name>

    <component>
        <component-type>org.primefaces.component.CaliforniaMenu</component-type>
        <component-class>org.primefaces.california.component.menu.CaliforniaMenu</component-class>
    </component>

    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
            <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.CaliforniaMenuRenderer</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>org.primefaces.california.component.menu.CaliforniaMenuRenderer</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>

    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>org.primefaces.california.backend.config.RequestInterceptor</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>

</faces-config>
```

startup
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9qNb.png)

Comment: Don't mix jsf and spring annotations on a class

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed#answer-18388289

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to externalize Spring Boot application.properties to tomcat/lib folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017064/how-to-externalize-spring-boot-application-properties-to-tomcat-lib-folder)